# How do I fix a bad Windows installation in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows

Basically, there was a security issue in the drivers for my graphics card. It was a 64-bit card and I installed 32-bit Windows.

Apparently, before SP1 was available, which fixed that issue, 6 trojan horses got in. They stopped SP1 from installing. After going through the ringer several times, I finally talked to a person who knew the problem. It was something about how the drivers tried to transfer between the 32-bit OS and the 64-bit card that left me open.

Ever since, my computer has been slow and has had weird issues. Like tinypic wouldn't ever load. Also, certain programs wouldn't install.

So I eventually talk to the dude that knew the problem and he takes the reigns and does some diagnostics. He tells me that to fix it I have to format the hard drive and do a fresh install. I'm okay with that because I was planning on it anyway, to upgrade to the 64-bit version.

The problem is, how do I do that? I have the disk to install the new copy, but when I go to install it, it tells me I can't and to check the log file. However, I don't know where that log file is, and it wiped my install of Windows out. How do I find the file and as a different route to get to the goal, how do I zero out the drive from Ubuntu 12.04? (I installed the 64-bit version just the other day)

Answer (score 2):

Boot from Ubuntu live cd and install a software called bleachbit where you can wipe uneeded inforamtion from your hard drive.more over you can use Gparted after that to delete all partitoins and repartition again.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, fire up the live CD and run GParted. From there, delete all of your partitions. **WARNING: This will nuke all the data on your drive.**

Upon rebooting, you should be able to run the Windows installer from scratch.

Comment: Creating a new partition table is another alternative, with essentially the same effects.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Scott. Unfortunately it didn't work. It still shows an error that says that it cannot either find or create a system partition for the install. Is there a way to zero the drive? It might work slightly better.

Comment: In that case, the problem isn't with Ubuntu, but presumably is Windows-related, which would  make this question off-topic for Ask Ubuntu. You might try asking over on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) instead.

Comment: The only reason I asked here is because right now Ubuntu is the only operating system I have  installed and am trying whatever tools it offers first. Is there a way to zero out the drive in Ubuntu? I think if I can do that it might help.

Comment: If following the advice given I'm the two answers here doesn't solve your problem, then the problem isn't really one for Ubuntu. One more suggestion: to zero your drive, boot from the live CD and, assuming your hard drive is /dev/sda, do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda`.

Comment: Does it not work in a full install? Do I have to boot to the live cd?

Comment: You can't zero out a disk that you're currently using. Else how will the full install continue running with all its files nuked?

Comment: The disk that I am using is not the disk I want to zero out. They are two separate drives.

Comment: Why didn't you say so earlier? Your question is full of irrelevant details (such as your story about trojans) and missing important details. That's perhaps why it got closed, since it was difficult to tell through all the rambling what you wanted. Now, here's a relevant detail that you're only now divulging.

Comment: In that case, you can use your install if you want. Just *be sure* that the paths you pass to `dd` are correct, else you could end up partially blowing away the wrong disk, which would give you even more headaches.